# Aws s3 selectObjectContent by version id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-s3-select

Is there a way we can run select object content (s3 select) on specific version of s3 object using version Id?

I cannot find any references in select object content documentation to specify the version Id like we have version Id field in get Object request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found a solution based on the request posted to aws sdk git channel.

```
request.putCustomQueryParameter("versionId", "<Your-version-Id>");
```

The aws docs should be updated soon since it was missing from there.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like this is possible.

The `select_object_content()` function takes a Bucket and Key, but not a VersionId.

Comment: Yeah the sdk doesnt seem to support that but I am wondering if we can do something like key?versionId='xyz' since this is being done when you try to retrieve a versioned object but yeah no clear documentation on s3 select for version Id

Comment: I doubt that would be possible. The API is quite specific in what it is wanting as inputs. (But, feel free to try!)